# Chef EC2 EBS Volume Using AWS Cookbook InvalidInstanceIDNotFound

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, chef-infra, chef-recipe, knife

I'm using the [Chef provided AWS cookbook](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/aws) (v2.7.2) to create and attach an EBS volume on an Ubuntu Server 14.04.02 LTS HVM ec2 instance during the initial bootstrapped chef-client run. I'm hosting my own chef server (12.1.0-1_amd64). Using knife-ec2, I create the aws instance and bootstrap the runlist via the following command:

```
knife ec2 server create --region us-east-1 --availability-zone us-east-1a --node-name my-server --run-list "role[my-role]" --image ami-d05e75b8 --flavor c3.large --ebs-size 16 --ebs-volume-type gp2 --subnet subnet-mySubnetId --associate-public-ip --server-connect-attribute public_ip_address --ssh-user ubuntu --ssh-key my-pem --identity-file /path/to/my-pem.pem -y
```

However, when the recipe executes that creates and attaches the volume, the volume successfully creates, but fails to attach to my instance. The following error keeps occuring:

```
Aws::EC2::Errors::InvalidInstanceIDNotFound: The instance ID 'i-36a93b84' does not exist
```

The following code is in my recipe (taken from the example on the cookbook page):

```
include_recipe 'aws'

aws_ebs_volume "backup_volume" do
  aws_access_key aws['aws_access_key_id']
  aws_secret_access_key aws['aws_secret_access_key']
  size 16
  device "/dev/sdi"
  availability_zone "us-east-1a"
  action [ :create, :attach ]
end
```

I verified 'i-36a93b84' is the id of the instance knife-ec2 creates and the chef-client is executing on, so it does exist. Also, I validated that I'm creating the volume in the same availability zone as the instance.

I've read some posts about [AWS's Eventual Consistency](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/query-api-troubleshooting.html#eventual-consistency), but have no idea how to handle this during a bootstrapped chef-client run, since the recipe runs immediately after the instance is created.

Is there a way to create an additional mount at the time knife-ec2 creates the aws server, or am I trying to attach a volume in an unorthodox manner?

Chef client output during the recipe:

```
  Recipe: my-cookbook::backupvolume
      * aws_ebs_volume[backup_volume] action create[2015-07-17T11:57:05+00:00] INFO: Processing aws_ebs_volume[backup_volume] action create (my-cookbook::backupvolume line 49)
      [2015-07-17T11:57:05+00:00] DEBUG: Providers for generic aws_ebs_volume resource enabled on node include: [LWRP provider aws_ebs_volume from cookbook aws]
      [2015-07-17T11:57:05+00:00] DEBUG: Provider for action create on resource aws_ebs_volume[backup_volume] is LWRP provider aws_ebs_volume from cookbook aws
      [2015-07-17T11:57:05+00:00] DEBUG: Instance ID is i-36a93b84
      [2015-07-17T11:57:05+00:00] DEBUG: Instance's availability zone is us-east-1a
      [2015-07-17T11:57:05+00:00] DEBUG: Created new  volume vol-4842ecc4
      [2015-07-17T11:57:05+00:00] DEBUG: Volume is creating
      [2015-07-17T11:57:08+00:00] INFO: Volume vol-4842ecc4 is available
        - create a volume with id= size=16 availability_zone=us-east-1a and update the node data with created volume's id
        * aws_ebs_volume[backup_volume] action attach[2015-07-17T11:57:08+00:00] INFO: Processing aws_ebs_volume[backup_volume] action attach (my-cookbook::backupvolume line 49)
      [2015-07-17T11:57:08+00:00] DEBUG: Providers for generic aws_ebs_volume resource enabled on node include: [LWRP provider aws_ebs_volume from cookbook aws]
      [2015-07-17T11:57:08+00:00] DEBUG: Provider for action attach on resource aws_ebs_volume[backup_volume] is LWRP provider aws_ebs_volume from cookbook aws
      [2015-07-17T11:57:08+00:00] DEBUG: Attaching vol-4842ecc4 as /dev/sdi


        ================================================================================
        Error executing action `attach` on resource 'aws_ebs_volume[backup_volume]'
        ================================================================================

        Aws::EC2::Errors::InvalidInstanceIDNotFound
        -------------------------------------------
        The instance ID 'i-36a93b84' does not exist

        Cookbook Trace:
        ---------------
        /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/aws/providers/ebs_volume.rb:212:in `attach_volume'
        /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/aws/providers/ebs_volume.rb:70:in `block (2 levels) in class_from_file'
        /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/aws/providers/ebs_volume.rb:68:in `block in class_from_file'

        Resource Declaration:
        ---------------------
        # In /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/my-cookbook/recipes/backupvolume.rb

         49:       aws_ebs_volume "backup_volume" do
         50:         aws_access_key aws['aws_access_key_id']
         51:         aws_secret_access_key aws['aws_secret_access_key']
         52:         size 16
         53:         device "/dev/sdi"
         54:         description "TEST BACKUP"
         55:         availability_zone "us-east-1a"
         56:         action [ :create, :attach ]
         57:       end
         58:

        Compiled Resource:
        ------------------
        # Declared in /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/my-cookbook/recipes/backupvolume.rb:49:in `from_file'

        aws_ebs_volume("backup_volume") do
          action [:create, :attach]
          updated true
          retries 0
          retry_delay 2
          default_guard_interpreter :default
          declared_type :aws_ebs_volume
          cookbook_name "my-cookbook"
          recipe_name "backupvolume"
          aws_access_key "********"
          aws_secret_access_key "********"
          size 16
          device "/dev/sdi"
          description "TEST BACKUP"
          availability_zone "us-east-1a"
          timeout 180
          volume_type "standard"
          piops 0
        end
```

Here is the stacktrace:

```
Aws::EC2::Errors::InvalidInstanceIDNotFound: aws_ebs_volume[backup_volume] (my-cookbook::backupvolume line 49) had an error: Aws::EC2::Errors::InvalidInstanceIDNotFound: The instance ID 'i-36a93b84' does not exist
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.0.48/lib/seahorse/client/plugins/raise_response_errors.rb:15:in `call'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.0.48/lib/seahorse/client/plugins/param_conversion.rb:22:in `call'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.0.48/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/response_paging.rb:10:in `call'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.0.48/lib/seahorse/client/plugins/response_target.rb:18:in `call'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.0.48/lib/seahorse/client/request.rb:70:in `send_request'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.0.48/lib/seahorse/client/base.rb:216:in `block (2 levels) in define_operation_methods'
/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/aws/providers/ebs_volume.rb:212:in `attach_volume'
/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/aws/providers/ebs_volume.rb:70:in `block (2 levels) in class_from_file'
/opt/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/mixin/why_run.rb:52:in `call'
/opt/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/mixin/why_run.rb:52:in `add_action'
/opt/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/provider.rb:175:in `converge_by'
/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/aws/providers/ebs_volume.rb:68:in `block in class_from_file'
```

Comment: I tested leaving the initial ec2 instance running for a few hours and tried running the recipe again to create and attach a volume. Same error, can't find the instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due to my own foolishnes.

The AWS credentials in the databag were for an old decomissioned AWS account but the AWS credentials used to create the instance w/ knife were for the current AWS account.

Once they correct keys were put in the databag, the volume successfully created and attached!

Hope this helps someone in the future...